# iOS - Deploying an IPA gives "Could not peruse package" (Enterprise install)

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, enterprise, ipa

I have a PhoneGap/Cordova application that has been developed, built, tested, and even wirelessly deployed successfully.  So, the XCode project is set up correctly and the IPA we manually build works fine.

Now, we are trying to automate the builds using Jenkins.  I have Jenkins set up to call a shell script that calls xcodebuild (building an archive) and then calls xcrun to package and sign the results (we aren't changing the signing cert, so no signing parameters are supplied to xcrun).

Jenkins reports no errors during the build or signing process.  However, when we attempt the OTA install, it hangs --- so, off to the console.  The message we get is:

unknown installd[XXX] : ######## stage_package: Could not peruse package at /var/tmp/install_staging.BLAHBLAHBLAH
unknown installd[XXX] : ######## MobileInstallationInstall: Could not stage the package
unknown com.apple.itunesstored[152] : MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
unknown installd[XXX] : ######## handle_install: API failed
unknown installd[XXX] : ######## send_message: failed to send mach message of 71 bytes: 10000003
unknown installd[XXX] : ######## send_error: Could not send error response to client

The numbers (XXX and ########) change each time I attempt the install (even if I don't rebuild in between), so I don't think it's relevant, but in the latest attempts, it was 154 and 001ea000 followed by 160 and 00403000.

Searching the web for "could not peruse package" isn't very revealing, so I was hoping someone here has seen this or has some feedback on how I can get my automated build working properly.  Any thoughts on our automated process (xcodebuild as archive or xcrun without changing the signing certs) or anything on the errors we've seen?